# Characterization of logarithmic derivative of the gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

[image]

This is an exercise in the Conway that I am stuck at. I managed to solve (a) through (d) and I suspect that the (a)~(d) characterize the logarithmic derivative of the gamma function. However I cannot rigorously prove (e). Could anyone help me how to solve (e)?

Comment: Locating the poles of $\Gamma(s)$ is easy, but showing it has no zeros is harder. c) is a consequence of $\Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$. I know how to obtain d) from $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)-\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ is a bounded entire function.

Comment: How about (e)? Do you have any opinion?